# Why does PCGen say my Pathfinder horse's bite is 1d8 damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pcgen, animal-companions

I'm using the program PCGen to create my Pathfinder characters and I created a samurai. I created the mount and made it a large horse. When I load the character sheet for my horse on PCGen, it says that its Bite attack should do 1d8+4 (it has 18 STR) damage, but the other sources I'm seeing say that Bite should do 1d4 damage. Is there something I'm not seeing that's making my horse's Bite be 1d8 instead of 1d4 or is this a mistake?

There was a problem that I had before where it had me choose 2 favored classes (I was a half-elf) and I didn't know why so I thought it was a mistake too. It wasn't until later that I found out that being a half-elf allows you to pick 2 favored classes. This is why I'm wondering if I'm just again not seeing something that's causing the Bite to be 1d8.

Anyone know of anything that can change a horse's Bite from 1d4 to 1d8?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything. Your Mount works like an animal companion, but those also seem to deal damage as normal for an animal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PCGen is wrong here. A Samurai's Mount works like a druids animal companion, and uses the base statistics described under animal companion for a [Horse Companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Horse), including a bite attack with 1d4 base damage.

That said, the reason for the discrepancy in PCGen is that a Horse's Bite is exceptionally weak for its size.

[Universal Monster Rules: Natural Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks) has a list of natural attack types including typical damage values for all creature sizes. This table lists the Bite attack for a Large creature as 1d8. Note that these values are not fixed in any way, or representing any sort of rules, as indicated by the footnote:

> Individual creatures vary from this value as appropriate

Comment: I thought this was the case. I was hoping my horse was supposed to have 1d8 Bite damage but I was almost sure it had to be a mistake on PCGen. The only reason I even asked is because, like I said, I had that problem before on PCGen and it turned out to be because I just overlooked one of half-elf's abilities. Thanks everyone for your input and answers.